# WSO2 ESB System logs not working

Tags: logging, log4j, wso2, system, esb

Running WSO2 ESB 4.8.1. When in the Management Console having a look at the System Logs, it presents me a

```
The log must be configured to use the org.wso2.carbon.logging.core.util.MemoryAppender to view entries on the admin console
```

Regarding to this error I bumped on the a similar error in the Storage Server so I reconfigured the log4j properties. (https://wso2.org/jira/browse/SS-56)

When changing the CARBON_MEMORY entry to this (as the error states)

```
log4j.appender.CARBON_MEMORY=org.wso2.carbon.logging.core.util.MemoryAppender
```

I get the following error in the startup sequence of the ESB:

```
log4j:ERROR Could not instantiate appender named "CARBON_MEMORY".
```

What now?

Thanks for your input,

Olivier

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the CARBON_MEMORY as follows,

```
log4j.appender.CARBON_MEMORY=org.wso2.carbon.logging.appender.CarbonMemoryAppender
```

Comment: Hi, unfortunately that does not help. It actually is the initial value found in the log4j.properties file.
I still get the same message on the system logs:

`The log must be configured to use the org.wso2.carbon.logging.core.util.MemoryAppender to view entries on the admin console`

Comment: In the meantime I downloaded an older version of the ESB, 4.7, and this one seems to be logging everything just fine.